# How to change header in Wordpress Blog page and all Post pages only

Tags: wordpress, header, blogs

How to change header in Wordpress Blog page and all Post pages only.
I want a custom header in Blog page and all single posts page.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional tags within Wordpress:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Basically, you will need to create the content you want only for the blog and post pages and wrap this within the conditional tags:

P.S Don't forget to include the category, and archive pages - as well as the post pages.

is_single(), is_archive(), is_category()

```
    <?php if (is_single()) { ?>
    // This is a post page
    <?php } else { ?>
    //This is not a post page
    <?php } ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem, could you possibly rate up my answer as a gesture in return? Thanks

Comment: i have 0 reps, cant rate up

Answer (score 0):

To include different header for specific pages change `get_header($name)` function call inside templates and add `$name` attribute. Wordpress will load `header-{name}.php` if file exists, if not, default header `header.php` will be loaded. Check out template hierarchy for templates where you need to change get_header() function call ( single.php, page.php ).

Wordpress documentation:

- [get_header](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header)
- [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display)